# How to create a TextBlock and HyperlinkButton with xaml, uwp, and Visual Studio

Tags: c++, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm am following this tutorial to learn peer page navigation with uwp, xaml. Is the information correct.[tutorial_capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFSFG.png)

The closing tags do not have opening tags for the first part. And the types are not known in the second one. I'm using Visual Studio.
Here are the link to the tutorial and the code:
[link to tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/peer-to-peer-navigation-between-two-pages#Frame_and_Page_classes)

```
<Page
x:Class="NavApp1.Page1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:NavApp1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="Page 1" />
    </code>
    </pre>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <colgroup>
        <col width="100%" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr class="header">
            <th align="left">XAML</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <HyperlinkButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Click to go to page 2" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click"/>
            </code>
            </pre>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You seem to be looking at [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/peer-to-peer-navigation-between-two-pages). It is broken. The sample XAML is messed up with the page's HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously that the code snippet plugin of the website temporary broken is, the right way to create a `TextBlock` and `HyperlinkButton` in XAML code is like this:

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
     <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="Page 1" />
     <HyperlinkButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Click to go to page 2" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click"/>
 </Grid>
```

Seems that you are new to UWP app development, to begin with it, you may refer to [Create a "hello world" app in C++ (Windows 10)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-basic-windows-10-app-in-cpp).

Also here are some official [Universal Windows app samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples), you may take a look.